# Export Data from SQL to CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, csv, export-to-csv

I'm using EntityFramework to access a sql server to return data.  The data needs to be formatted into a tab delimited file.  I then want to compress the data to return to the user.

I can do the select, and then iterate over the EF objects and format all the data into one big string- but this takes forever (I'm returning abouit 800k rows).  The query itself is quite fast, but its just the creating of the csv file in memory that is killing it.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd) that describes how to use sqlcmd to do this directly as an export (but with csv) with sql which seems very promising, but I'm unclear how to pass the `-E` and other parameters to `ExecuteSqlCommand()`... or if it is even meant for this.

I tried to do something like this:

```
var test = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("select Chromosome c, 
StartLocation sl, Endlocation el, GeneName gn from Gencode where c = chr1", 
"-E", "-Q", new SqlParameter("-s", "\t"));
```

But of course that didn't work...

Any suggestions as to how to go about this?  I'm using EF 6.1 if that matters.

Comment: SQLCMD is a command line utility.  The SQLParameter is used for passing the parameters to the SQL Command.

Comment: Similar Question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178114/net-entity-framework-to-csv

Answer (score 0):

Alternate option using simple method.
F5-->store result--> keep file name 
[image]